# vertical align inline-block element

Tags: html, css, inline, centering, display

So, trying to learn the basics of css and still struggling with something that should be fairly simple. Centering a div with a display of inline-block vertically. I have tried `vertical align: middle;`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 580px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="logo"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;?

Comment: Refer this example https://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA

Answer (score 0):

See example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyz2xdsb/)

Add CSS

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin:-25vh 0vh 0vh -25vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
Set container height as 100%.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

`text-align:center`

Or

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

For display Div center. [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)